# Synonymize [json-web-token] to [jwt]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

There is currently two tags for JSON Web Tokens also known as JWT: [json-web-token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json-web-token) and [jwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jwt). Unfortunately I don't have high enough score on those, so I can't suggest the synonymization. [jwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jwt) is currently the more used tag with around 652 questions where as [json-web-token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json-web-token) has only 46. So I hereby suggest that [json-web-token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json-web-token) would be made synonym for [jwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jwt).

Comment: I would prefer making the full name the master, but whatever works.

Comment: current state is 3,547 tagged jwt, 225 tagged json-web-token and among them many tagged with both.. I didn't even notice the latter one and would also suggest to get rid of it or make it a synonym of jwt

Comment: bumping this up, as I just noticed some one wanted to add the other tag to the first one in some [edit review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18097649).As per this comment, `jwt` has now 289 followers, 4.1k questions whereas `json-web-token` has 14 followers and 259 questions

Comment: looks like this has been solved now. Thanks to whoever did it :)